# JavaFX Custom component in the same project and scene builder

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, custom-component, scenebuilder

I have a small question.
I have seen on a blog that you have to create a .jar from a custom component and load that file into scene builder, but in my project all custom components are in the main project, do I have to create a .jar from the project and import it, because that seems pretty weird.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both a FXML or a jar and load it into the SceneBuilder, independent of the Project. You can  create Templates and load them into the SceneBuilder to reuse them in many Projects.

Look at the right side of the Library-Searchbar in the Top-Left Corner. If you click on that gear-wheel you will see the Menupoint - "Import JAR/FXML File".

Comment: Thank you, one last question, you can't show a JavaFX class thing without an FXML in scene builder right? Like you extends BorderPane and put content in it by code.

Comment: Sorry i didn't try it out yet, but thinking about it that you can add a jar in it it could work. Why don't just make a simple little pane with a button and try loading it in the SceneBuilder? ;)